# Why do I receive "File corrupted!" error after changing library ID from @rpath to @executable_path?

Tags: dynamic-linking, dylib, rpath, executable-path

I use Qt 5.12 with XCode 10 for building my desktop application. I've received a .dylib from a 3rd party in order to integrate it into my application. I've modified my .pro file to add the library in the LIBS variable.

If I leave the library id as `@rpath/test.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)` everything works fine.
If I use `install_name_tool` and change the library id to `@executable_path/../Frameworks/test.dylib`, I get a weird error after starting my app:

> File corrupted! This program has been manipulated and maybe
> it's infected by a Virus or cracked. This file won't work anymore.

Note: I am sure that the library is available at `@executable_path/../Frameworks` so that is not the issue.

Comment: Is the dylib codesigned?

Comment: I believe not:
codesign --verify --deep --verbose test.dylib
lib/test.dylib: code object is not signed at all
In architecture: x86_64

Comment: Then there must be some proprietary mechanism in place to detect tampering.